# How can you control the values that get returned when filtering?

Tags: podio

I'm using the Podio API to get the data from the company into Power BI, only am I getting way more data back than what I need; I only need the field values.

I've tried `https://api.podio.com/item/app/appid/filter?fields=item.view()` to limit the amount of data that I recieve. Problem is, it removes the wrong data. As mentioned before, I only need the field values of the apps. Is it currently possible to achieve this, or is there another way to control what fields are returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, figured it out:

In Power BI, I've used `Pivot Column` on the column which contained the columns that I need, and the column with their respected values. (Make sure to select `Don't aggregate` in the advanced options)

Then I simply removed the columns I didn't need.